# add user to role

Tags: 7, forms, users

i'm trying to create custom drupal 7 module , i'm using 'user_roles()' function to get all the roles in the system , and then i assign those roles to checkboxes API Form Control

```
  $form['roles_group'] = array(
  '#type' => 'checkboxes',
  '#options' => drupal_map_assoc(user_roles()),
  '#default_value' => isset($field['roles_group']) ? $field['roles_group'] : '',
  '#required' => TRUE
);
```

in the display mode i'm getting a list of checkboxes like this :

```
<input type="checkbox" id="edit-mtc-roles-utilisateur-anonyme" name="mtc_roles[utilisateur anonyme]" value="utilisateur anonyme" class="form-checkbox">
```

in the :

```
name="mtc_roles[utilisateur anonyme]"
```

the system automatically put the human readable name in the 'Name' attribute of the inputs

and that's makes me wonder if there is a drupal 7 function that can assign a role by the 'human readable name' to a specific user , or do i have to fix attr  '#options' in the form checkbox API

> PS : the same issue with the content types

thanks in advance ^^

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by 'the same issue with the content types' but it is probably best to post a different question outlining the problem, rather than trying to get two solutions with one question.

Comment: @Triskelion 'the same issue with the content types' means when i try to get all the content type and add them in checkboxes list , i'm getting the same problem with the 'name' attr

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually you do not assign the user to a role, but the reverse. You assign the role to the user.

First use the following to load the role using the plain langauge role name:

```
$new_role = user_role_load_by_name($role_name);
```

This loads the role object.

Then load the specific user using their user id:

```
$account = user_load($uid);
```

Then update the roles as follows:

```
$account->roles[$new_role->rid] = $new_role->name;
```

And save the user:

```
user_save($account);
```

This will add the role to the specified user.