# Dynamically add User into a role

Tags: 7, webforms, users, payment-gateways

I have set up a Drupal site to connect to an external payment gateway (not using Drupal Commerce) for subscription-based billing. So making use of Drupal Webform, I have created forms for users to provide their payment information. Live site will be behind SSL.

What I would like to know is:

1. Where do I start by taking the details of the completed Webform and submitting it to the Payment Gateway's XML web service? Essentially, what I'm looking for is some hook into when the form is filled in, to trigger some code (which I already have setup and tested in a separate plain PHP app) to call the Web Service; and then
2. Based on the response that I get from the Payment Gateway, to add the logged in user to a specific role?

Your help will be greatly appreciated! Thank you in advance

Comment: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/96529/how-do-you-implement-a-custom-submit-handler-in-hook-form-alter and http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/75060/add-user-to-role?rq=1 should cover it I think. Maybe have a peek and update this question with specifics if you can't get it working?

Comment: Oh this one too: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/5802/how-can-i-find-the-form-id-of-a-form

Comment: Thanks Clive! I'll use these to go along with freality's suggestion below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you could utilize hooks like [hook_form_FORM_ID_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7) setting custom #validate & #submit functions or hook_webform_submission_insert, I've had better success using the [Payment module](https://www.drupal.org/project/payment) and writing a custom Payment Method class.

Comment: Hi freality, thank you for the suggestion! I didn't realise that Payment module could be used as a stand-alone solution.